# How to generate number in ascending order using the expression $a^2\cdot b^3$ where $a$ and $b$ are distinct primes.

Tags: number-theory

How to generate numbers in ascending order using the expression $a^2\cdot b^3$ where $a$ and $b$ are distinct primes.

Here are a couple of examples :
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\text{No}&a&b&a^2\cdot b^3\\
\hline
1&3&2&72\\
2&2&3&108\\
3&5&2&200\\
4&7&2&392\\
5&2&5&500\\
6&5&3&675\\
7&11&2&968\\
8&3&5&1125\\
9&7&3&1323\\
10&13&2&1352\\
\end{array}$$
Is there a way I can stop at $1000$th number without pre computing say $100000$ numbers, and then sorting and arriving at $1000$th number ?

Comment: What do you assume as "given"? Perhaps a list of the 1000 smallest prime numbers? (If not, then - before you ask your question - you must ask the much simpler one: how do I find the 1000th prime number?) Then - suppose the prime numbers are given. Why start with a^2 * b^3? Do you know how to solve the problem, say, for a*b (products of two distinct primes)? If not, why would you expect that a^2 * b^3 is easier to handle than a * b?

Comment: You made a good point, but doesn't really answer my question. I didn't say its easy or hard. I don't know how to proceed so I posted the question thinking if somebody can help.

Comment: I don't think you will have to compute $100,000$ numbers. You may have to compute more than $1000$ numbers but probably not much more  than that.

Answer (score 1):

I got Matlab to calculate numbers up to $10^8$, or a hundred billion.
The $N$th number, over that range, was about $9N^{2.5}/\ln N$.  The $1000$th number was $42797187 = 3^31259^2$.
The largest prime involved in the first thousand was $2311$, which is the $344$th prime.
According to my formula, the biggest prime $p$, which will be with $2^3p^2\approx 9N^{2.5}/\ln N$, is roughly $p=N^{1.25}/\sqrt{\ln N}$.

Comment: It would be nice to know how many $a^3b^2$'s did you actually calculate to find the first $N$ of them. Or did you just factor _all_ numbers and select those of the form $a^3b^2$?

Comment: Start with $a=2$, and let $b$ be all the primes from $3$ to $\sqrt{10^8/8}$.  Then let $a=3$ and $b$ all the primes from $2$ to $\sqrt{10^8/27}$, except $b=3$, and so on.  I had a $10000000$-vector of zeros, and let $x(a*a*a*b*b)=1$.  Finally I found the positions of all the nonzero $x$-numbers.

Comment: Fine. So you did actually calculate all numbers of the form $a^3b^2$ up to $10^8$, of which there are 1444. As to me, that's not much of an overhead. Certainly not 100000 instead of 1000, as the OP suggested.